# Are there any issues what so ever with running Eclipse with OpenJDK under Linux?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

NOTE:  This question is from 2014.  As of 2019 the situation is different.  OpenJDK is underlying all the various distributions, and should behave the same for all.

---

The standard cure for fixing Java problems with Linux distributions like Ubuntu is to say "Use the Sun JDK instead of OpenJDK".  For several reasons I'd like to just use the Java shipping with Ubuntu instead of having to install and download from partner repositories or download tarballs.

I have played some with Eclipse 3.7.1 under Ubuntu 11.10 and not found any glaring showstoppers.

Question is:  Is there *anything* not working correctly with the default installation of (EDIT: OpenJDK) Java on Ubuntu at all, or is there something I should look out for?

Comment: Why don't you just try? Any answer you will get here could be outdated with the next version of Eclipse or OpenJDK or even Ubuntu patches. Not sure what you're expecting here.

Comment: @Mat - "Just trying" is not a good way to discover subtle issues probably rooted in combination of hard- and software, except you have lots of time and lots of different machine configs. The "use sun's distro instead of openjdk" appears prominently when starting intellij on linux. The corresponding [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-70860) as well as the [discussion forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/305004) fail to provide any further info. Sounds like an urban myth to me :)

Comment: @Mat, as stated in my question I _have_ tried.  Some differences can be very elusive.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: so you tried, and apparently nothing you use fails to work... Still not sure what you're after.

Comment: @Mat, a long time ago I spotted a difference in the way the date formatter worked between OpenJDK and the Sun JDK.  Do you agree that such differences may not show in a "kick the tires" session?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: so this has nothing to do with Eclipse, you're just wondering if there are bugs in OpenJDK?

Comment: @Mat You know of the episode where the dependency of Eclipse of the vendor name reported by the JVM caused it to stop working when Oracle changed "Sun" to "Oracle"?   Even if it happened when upgrading the JVM the bug was still in Eclipse.  Clearer now?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I understand, but I still think your question is not answerable. All software has bugs. Some are major for some people and transparent for others. Some get fixed fast, some lie around for ages. "Is there _anything_ not working correctly...": most likely, the answer is yes featureX. Tomorrow it could be featureY subtely broken by an unrelated change somewhere. Unless you've got a **very** specific use case with fixed versions of everything and don't plan to upgrade, any answer you get could be outdated the next time Ubuntu releases a patch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4981/discussion-between-thorbjorn-ravn-andersen-and-mat)

Answer (score 3):

Now OpenJDK 7 is a standard implementation of Java. Oracle JDK 7 is built on openjdk7 code, except some additional features, which are not included in Java specification

So there should not be a performance difference(I can not see it). Ubuntu 11.10 has openjdk7 in the repository.

Otherwise Openjdk6 is really slower then SunJDK6. So if you need to use jdk6, it is better to switch to Sun JDK6

Comment: "should not" is a bit vague.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Now OpenJDK 7 is a standard implementation of Java.
Oracle JDK 7 is build on openjdk7 code, except some additional features, which are not included in Java specification.
I do not see any differences in performance for these versions.

Answer (score 3):

I've had quite a lot of problems with various plugins (Android Update) using the openjdk6 on Ubuntu 11.10. Sun JRE 'just fixed' the problems.

I can't just update to java 7 because I'm working with android open source (AOSP) which does not support compilation with java 7 yet. It only somewhat supports building with openjdk6.

Sometimes the bleeding edge is just bleeding. For now I'm staying with Sun JDK 6. Its the reference implementation and appears to 'just work'. Which is what I'm going for. These are tools for me, my primary purpose here is not to debug my tools before use.

Kudos for the OpenJDK folks for being 99.9% there. Once everyone else catches up with them life will be great.

Oh and Oracle can stuff-it for the license change that caused many of these problems. Larry does not need another boat.

-JZ

Comment: You can compile for Java 6 with Java 7

Answer (score 0):

It's not that there's "anything not working correctly with the default installation of Java on Ubuntu". I've used OpenJDK a lot on Ubuntu and Fedora Core and never encountered bizzare errors.

However, and this is a big "however", if you use fancy frameworks like Hibernate or some of Spring's stuff (like AspectJ stuff), which do exotic, non-standard stuff (like bytecode modifications, recompilation on the fly etc etc), you WILL get into trouble with OpenJDK but they will all work ok with Oracle/Sun JDK. I always switch from OpenJDK to Oracle JDK when doing this kind of development.

Comment: When was the last time you ran into trouble with OpenJDK?

Comment: When building my JPA2 & Hibernate 3.6 & CDI & EJB 3.1 Glassfish project under Fedora 10 with Glassfish 3. I've spend 30 minutes trying to figure out how to fix it, finally switched to Oracle JDK 6 update 20+ and it worked ok. Also on windows i didn't get the error with Oracle JDK. I had similar issues with JRockIt on Windows.

Comment: I was merely looking for an approximate date.  But so your environment apparently only runs correctly with the Sun JVM in the first place.  May be hard to find - there is an AIX release now of Glassfish which do not have Sun JVM dependencies.