# what is the eclipse compatible version for openjdk1.7 in windows 7 64 bit OS

Tags: eclipse, java

I have windows 7 64 bit OS in which I used to work with eclipse Juno Service Release2 version and Oracle JDK 1.7. Now as per my new project requirements I had to change my JDK from Oracle JDK to OpenJDK 1.7. I have un-installed all the other jdk's from my machine and installed OpenJDK1.7(64 bit version). Now I am facing issues with eclipse, I am able to open eclipse IDE but if I perform any operations like opening an existing project or trying to run any programs/project it is getting crashed or getting hanged. I have to end the process from the taskbar and try again and again. Below is the popup screen that I am getting after eclipse crashes.

Can some one tell me how to resolve this issue? I have seen some blogs saying there is a bug with eclise and OpenJDK with Ubuntu and mac OS but no issues reported for windows. So if there is way to fix this issue please let me know (or) please suggest any eclipse version the is compatible with OpenJDK1.7 and windows7.

[image: Eclipse Crashing error Screen]

Comment: This q&a may help, not exactly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8123157/2796832

Comment: @JonahGraham: thanks for the link, But the link did not help me. I am looking for the compatible version of Eclipse for OpenJDK7. I never had any issues with Oracle JDK7+ Eclipse Juno which I am using for past 8 months but as per my requirements I had to change my JDK to OpenJDK and Eclipse is getting closed each and every time when I perform any action in it. I have gone through many links and forums to figure out the issue but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version of solution to my issue which was mentioned above.

Installed Oracle JDK1.7 on my system and did not set the path for this. I have updated the `eclipse.ini` file with (found in eclipse root directory)

`-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javaw.exe` parameter. so that Eclipse starts with Oracle jdk 
and in

`Eclipse->Windows->Preferences` window

under `Java->Installed JREs->Add(under Installed JREs)`

added a new entry to point out the OpenJDK1.7 version so that my project uses  OpenJDK version. This solved unusual crashing of Eclipse